# How to String format urls that contain path parameter

Tags: java, string, format

I have the url `https://www.someurl.com/v2/path/[PARAM1]?key=[PARAM1]2`.
I want to do the following

```
final String URL = "https://www.someurl.com/v2/path/%?key=%";
String val = String.format(URL, "details", "testing");
System.out.println(val);
```

But I am getting an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '?'
at java.util.Formatter.checkText(Formatter.java:2547)
at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2533)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2469)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2423)
at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2845)
at split.StringStuff.main(StringStuff.java:22)
```

How might I make it work?

Comment: You should consider using URI templates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the placeholders are for `String` values, you need to use `%s` instead of just `%`.

```
final String URL = "https://www.someurl.com/v2/path/%s?key=%s";
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use %s character in format, not just %.